# How to echo php information into form on parent page

Tags: php

I have a link to customer inquires form at the bottom of my order form. Once the customer clicks this link it opens the inquiry form. I want the product number from the order form to auto fill into the inquiry form and be submitted to me. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp

Answer (score 2):

Example

```
<?php

    $customer_id = $_GET['c_id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_id = $customer_id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

?>
```

Then in your form you echo

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="customer_name" value="<?= $row['customer_name'] ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="customer_email" value="<?= $row['customer_email'] ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Okay" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

3 Possible choices.

- DB: If order information is available on DB you can attach order id (primary key of order table) to the link and fetch it upon loading inquiry form page.
- SESSION: Similar to DB.
- AJAX/JQuery: If none of them are available, you can use ajax to send current values as $_GET values and fill inquiry forms. (http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml)